# How to get fragment manager in custom component using android annotations?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-annotations

```
@EView public class BaseButton extends Button implements OnClickListener {                                                     private SherlockFragment nextFragment;
public BaseButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated m ethod stub
    //how to get fragment manager?
      FragmentManager fragmentManager = app.getFragmentManager();
}

public SherlockFragment getNextFragment() {
    return nextFragment;
}

public void setNextFragment(SherlockFragment nextFragment) {
    this.nextFragment = nextFragment;
}

}
```

I want to add next fragment dynamically to my custom view using android annotations

Answer (score 2):

View shouldn't be aware where it's placed (Fragment or Activity). You should find View and set OnClickListener externally or provide FragmentManager (I don't think if it's best idea to use FragmentManager inside View like in your sample).

Comment: I agree, a listener has to be implemented and handle outside the component itself

Comment: This is true in many cases, but there are cases where it's reasonable to want to handle a UI event inside a custom component. For example your consumer provided another type of listener and you want to handle this event so you can call that listener. It means the individual views within your custom component can remain private implementation details while only exposing relevant events/data to the outside.

Answer (score -2):

Supposed your FragmentActivity is MainActivity.class to get FragmentManager

```
((MainActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Note : check import of `MainActivity`

Comment: i don't know how to call the mainActivity/any fragments in my component class

Comment: @wolverine just use `AppCompatActivity` rather than `MainActivity`